# Getting this error message to configure bulid path in AppiumDriver(url, cap)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APlvX.png)

Hi All,
I'm getting below error message same also available in screen shot.
""the type io.appium.java_client.remote.Appium Command Executor cannot be resolved because it is indirectly referenced from required .class""
Can any one please help me to get it resolved. I dont know why I'm getting this error message and which jar file i need to add. I'm using Appium with selenium.

Comment: Posting images of code is frowned upon on SO. Please post the code, properly formatted, and include the full error message so we can help you.

Comment: Need some more explanation

Comment: Thanks guys! Problem has been resolved. I was using older version of eclipse. Now its working fine.